# Lua digit pattern matching not capturing

Tags: lua, lua-patterns, multiple-assignment

I'm attempting to match `Sword` and `2` in the following string.

> You receive loot [Sword]x2.

This is where I've made it so far.  Sword matches fine and is saved in the item variable. qty, however, always returns 'No qty' regardless of the input string.

```
local item, qty = msg:match('%[(.+)%]x?(%d?)') or 'No item', 'No qty'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not your pattern, it's the way the multiple assignment together with `or` works.  What you have is actually (note the bold parens):

`local item, qty =`**`(`**`msg:match('%[(.+)%]x?(%d?)') or 'No item'`**`)`**`, 'No qty'`

So, `qty` will *always* be assigned `'No qty'`.  I don't think this problem can be solved in a single statement. You'll have to do something like this:

```
local item, qty = msg:match('%[(.+)%]x?(%d?)')
item = item or 'No item'
qty = qty or 'No qty'
```

or

```
local item, qty = msg:match('%[(.+)%]x?(%d?)')
item, qty = item or 'No item', qty or 'No qty'
```

Concerning the pattern, you might want to use `%[(.+)%]x?(%d*)`, i.e. `*` instead of `?` for quantities of 10 or more.